# Need help to insert many rows in my SaaS project using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, saas

I'm trying to develop a SaaS project. I have to, when the new company register, it automatically registers all permission params and permission groups it's going to have. The code is working including a company, a user in that company within the permission group Admin and he has clients view permission.

Now I need to add the other permissions the same way, they have to be created and added to the admin group just created. I'm trying this, but it only adds the first param (clients_view) and not the second param (clients_edit)

```
    <?php

require_once 'config.php';


$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
$cnpj = isset($_POST['cnpj']) ? $_POST['cnpj'] : null;
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

if (empty($name) || empty($cnpj) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) ){
    echo "Please fill all fields";
    exit;
}

//Creates the new company
$PDO = db_connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO companies (name, cnpj) VALUES(:name, :cnpj)";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':cnpj', $cnpj);
$stmt->execute();

//creates permission param  clients_view
$id_company = $PDO->lastInsertId();
$name = 'clients_view';
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO permission_params (id_company, name) VALUES (:id_company, :name)";
$stmt2 = $PDO->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->bindParam(':id_company', $id_company);
$stmt2->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt2->execute();

//creates permission group Admin with param clients_view
$params = $PDO->lastInsertId();
$name = 'Admin';
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO permission_groups (id_company, name, params) VALUES (:id_company,:name, :params)";
$stmt3 = $PDO->prepare($sql3);
$stmt3->bindParam(':id_company', $id_company);
$stmt3->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt3->bindParam(':params', $params);
$stmt3->execute();

//create new user and adds to Admin group
$id_group = $PDO->lastInsertId();
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, id_group, id_company) "
        . "VALUES (:username, :email, :password, :id_group, :id_company)";
$stmt4 = $PDO->prepare($sql4);
$stmt4->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt4->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt4->bindParam(':password',md5($password));
$stmt4->bindParam(':id_group', $id_group);
$stmt4->bindParam(':id_company', $id_company);
$stmt4->execute();


//creates permission clients_edit
// NOT WORKING
$name = 'clients_edit';
$sql5 = "INSERT INTO permission_params (name) VALUES (:name) WHERE id_company=:id_company";
$stmt5 = $PDO->prepare($sql5);
$stmt5->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt5->bindParam(':id_company', $id_company);
$stmt5->execute();


//Insert permission clients_view in group Admin
//NOT WORKING
$params = $PDO->lastInsertId();
$sql6 = "INSERT INTO permission_groups ( params) VALUES ( :params) WHERE name=:name AND id_company=:id_company";
$stmt6 = $PDO->prepare($sql6);
$stmt6->bindParam(':params', $params);
$stmt6->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt6->bindParam(':id_company', $id_company);
$stmt6->execute();


header('Location: index.php');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO permission_params (name) VALUES (:name) WHERE id_company=:id_company
```

That's wrong. You can't INSERT that again in that ID. You can INSERT new with new ID, or you can UPDATE that ID with new name OR you can create new table there insert ID from this table and on that way connect some other table with this table. If you know what I mean, maybe not the best explanation :D

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, or if I'll be able to explain (English is not my 1st language). I want to insert a new id on the table permission_params, but it has to be related to the variable id_company so this is created in the correct company. I tried to update, it just deleted the 1st one and created the second one. I need both (it'll be 9 params in the end) Table id_params has id, id_company and name.

Comment: English is also not my 1 st language, so to me is also not easy to explain :D Maybe you can try on this way. Add company into companies table, and then use that id in permission_params, something in way: $sql5 = "INSERT INTO permission_params (name, company_id) VALUES (:name, company_id); And later when yout want to check permissions for that company you get that from that table. So basically point is you need to dived that, because you cant override some insert with new insert, you can just update

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I'll mark this answer as correct, but can you help me a little bit more before? Now I need to add those two params in my id_group. I tried this same logic, but it created new id, which doesn't help. If I update, it just overrides the previous one, and I need both, ie: table permission_groups id: 5, id_group=10, params=1,2,3,4,5 where 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are the id's of these params I created.